# Foreach Loop to linq

Tags: linq, foreach

This might be very simple but I am not able to see data after converting

```
public void SearchGrid(int id, ObservableCollection<TestModel> msgField)
{ 
  foreach (var c in msgField)
    DisplayColor = c.Id == id ? Brushes.Blue : Brushes.Black;
}
```

Linq:

```
Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(msgField.Where(x => x.Id == id), x => { DisplayColor = Brushes.CadetBlue; });
```

Comment: That is the dumbest foreach loop ever. Are you foreaching to get to the last result? Post your actual code.

Comment: This is a continuation of my post here:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110114/c-sharp-wpf-highlight-selected-row-of-datagrid?noredirect=1#comment24757510_17110114

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, it's a bad idea to create queries that produce side effects.  I would personally rewrite this as:

```
DisplayColor = msgField.Any(x => x.Id == id) ? Brushes.Blue : Brushes.Black;
```

This produces the output I believe you are attempting to generate.  It will set the `DisplayColor` to blue or black based on whether there is a matching "msgField" element.

To get the same result as your current looping code, you could use:

```
if (msgField.Any())
    DisplayColor = msgField.Last().Id == id ? Brushes.Blue : Brushes.Black;
```

This will produce the same output as your loop, as your loop will overwrite `DisplayColor` with each iteration, so only the last item matters.

Comment: Thank you this explains a lot to me as I am new to LINQ. I posted this question from the feedback i got from my other post                             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110114/c-sharp-wpf-highlight-selected-row-of-datagrid?noredirect=1#comment24757510_17110114