# How to change RowBackground color of a datagrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, treeview

I am currently working on a WPF application MVVM pattern  where I have to create some sort of relationship between a treeview and a grid. The relationship is based on ID. The idea is to highlight a row with a id equal to the treenode id.

Display color property

```
    public Brush DisplayColor
    {
        set
        {
            _displayColor = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DisplayColor");
        }

        get { return _displayColor; }

    }
```

Select TreeNode value.id

```
    private MessageElementViewModel _selectedMessageElement;
    public MessageElementViewModel SelectedMessageElement
    {
        set
        {
            if (_selectedMessageElement == value) return;
            this._selectedMessageElement = value;
            SearchGrid(value.Id, messageFields);

        }
        get
        {
            return this._selectedMessageElement;
        }

    }
```

// search matching Id in the grid

```
     public void SearchGrid(int id, ObservableCollection<MessageFieldViewModel> msgField)
    {
         if (msgField.Any())
            DisplayColor = msgField.Last().Id == id ? Brushes.CadetBlue : Brushes.Black;
    }
```

XAML: Call the display color property to highlight a matching id.
DataGrid

TreeView:

```
      <TreeView Margin="644,137,6,6" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding MessageElements[0].Children,  Mode=TwoWay}"  

                  SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_OnSelectedItemChanged">
```

Code Behind for treeview select item;

```
    readonly MainWindowModel _mainWindowModel = new MainWindowModel();

    private void TreeView_OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        if (_mainWindowModel != null)
            _mainWindowModel.SelectedMessageElement = (MessageElementViewModel)e.NewValue;
    }
```

EDIT:

```
<DataGrid   ItemsSource="{Binding MessageFields}" Margin="4,0,380,6" Grid.Row="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  IsReadOnly="True"   SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedMessageField}"
                    RowBackground="{Binding Path=DisplayColor}">
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="*"  />      <!--Foreground="{Binding Path=DisplayColor}-->

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position" Binding="{Binding Position}" Width="*"   />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length" Binding="{Binding Length}" Width="*"  />
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Why is my is my display color property is not working for matching Ids?

Thank you all.

Comment: I don't really understand how you'd like to achieve this. There is only one `DisplayColor` property on your `MainViewModel`, right? And that is bound to the global `RowBackground` of your `DataGrid`. So either every row is going to be Black or every row is going to be CadetBlue. I think you should create a `DisplayColor` property on the ViewModel of your DataItems, so you can highlight one separate row.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the MVVM pattern please don't define Stuff from the VisualTree in your ViewModel like Windows, DataGrids, **Brushes**, and so on

so now to your question

this is an Simple example for: 
**How to change RowBackground color of a datagrid**

### XAML

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ColorSwitch}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
```

### Codebehind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new VM();
    }
}
```

### ViewModel

```
public class VM
{
    public List<myItem> Source {get;set;}

    public VM()
    {
        Source = new List<myItem>();
        Source.Add(new myItem{Field1 = "some Text", Field2 = "some other Text",ColorSwitch=false});
        Source.Add(new myItem{Field1 = "some Text", Field2 = "some other Text",ColorSwitch=false});
        Source.Add(new myItem{Field1 = "some Text", Field2 = "some other Text",ColorSwitch=true});
        Source.Add(new myItem{Field1 = "some Text", Field2 = "some other Text",ColorSwitch=false});
        Source.Add(new myItem{Field1 = "some Text", Field2 = "some other Text",ColorSwitch=true});
    }
}
```

### Simpleobject

```
public class myItem
{
    public string Field1 {get;set;}
    public string Field2 {get;set;}
    public bool ColorSwitch {get;set;}
}
```