# WPF: DataGridRow select

Tags: wpf, select, mvvm, datagrid

How to clean the previously selected row ?

I have this method that search for item with a given id.

```
   private void TreeView_OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {

        foreach (MessageFieldViewModel rowItem in Datagrid.ItemsSource)
        {

            if (_mainWindowModel != null)
                _mainWindowModel.SelectedMessageElement = (MessageElementViewModel)e.NewValue;

            var row = Datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(rowItem) as DataGridRow;

            if (_mainWindowModel != null && _mainWindowModel.SelectedMessageElement != null)
            {
                if (rowItem.Id == _mainWindowModel.SelectedMessageElement.Id)
                {
                    if (row != null)
                        row.Background = Brushes.DarkSalmon;
                }

                row.Background.ClearValue();
            }
            // if (item != null) row.Background.ClearValue(rowItem.Id);
            //  break;
        }
```

This selects the row of a given id. but if I want to select another Id The previous id is still selected. 
how can I remove previously selected Ids and show only the newly selected id?

Comment: it looks like this is part of your code behind so why does the View know's about the ViewModels?

Comment: @wiimaxx I didn't get your comment? Are you asking me how this method gets called? Please explain

Comment: no i just want to tell you what you are doing is wrong but no worries i'm on may way with a solution :D just some more minutes

Comment: thanks. You are right I didn't want to do it this way this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110114/c-sharp-wpf-highlight-selected-row-of-datagrid/17113992?noredirect=1#17113992.                 Was how I wanted to do it but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

ok so  here we go

**XAML**

```
<TreeView Name="Tree" Width="50" Height="100"
          ItemsSource="{Binding YourTree}" 
          SelectedItemChanged="Tree_SelectedItemChanged" 
          SelectedValuePath="yourIdProperty"/>
<DataGrid Name="myDatagrid" Width="100" Height="100"
          ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding YourSelectedItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
```

**Codebehind**

```
    private void Tree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        var tree = sender as TreeView;
        myDatagrid.SelectedValue = tree.SelectedValue;
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
    public List<yourClass> YourList { get; set; }

    private yourClass yourSelectedItem;
    public yourClass YourSelectedItem
    {
        get { return yourSelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            yourSelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("YourSelectedItem");
        }
    }
```

you need to set the `SelectedValuePath` based your Property which represent your Id but **not** as Binding just as string as example `"Id"`

Comment: I updated my code with your feedback. Here is the description : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110114/c-sharp-wpf-highlight-selected-row-of-datagrid                                            What I wanted to do was to highlight row with has a matching id with a the tree .Now I am not able to highlight my grid for matching ID. Can you look at my original post